# Criar um método para obter registros por id

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net

No meu CRUD quero criar um método `obterPorId(Cliente cli)` quero obter os registros pelo código, ou pelo nome, ou outro campo.

Como ficaria com o DataReader?

uma forma correta, usando um método que retorne um cliente, ex:

```
public Cliente obterPorId(Cliente cli)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Como você não deu maiores informações vou colocar algo que funcionaria um uma aplicação minha. Claro que você terá que fazer várias adaptações, usar o método condizentemente ou alterá-lo para cuidar de situações excepcionais ou fazer algo diferente de retornar nulo se nada for encontrado (embora no meu sistema eu faria diferente).

```
public Cliente ObterPorId(int id)
    using (connection) { //imagino que esta informação está disponível na classe
    using (var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT campo1, campo2 FROM Clientes WHERE Id = @id;", connection))
    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@id", id));
        connection.Open();
        Cliente cliente;
        if (reader.Read()) {
            cliente = new Cliente();
            cliente.campo1 = reader.GetString(0) //primeira coluna
            cliente.campo2 = reader.GetString(1) //segunda coluna
        }
    }
    return cliente;
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/ADO.NET/GetById.cs).

O `@id` é um parâmetro de *query*, ele será substituído pelo `id` passado para este método conforme o [`SqlParameter`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter.-ctor?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameter__ctor_System_String_System_Object_) usado em seguida.

Obviamente não testei mas a ideia geral é esta. Reforço que necessidades específicas farão o algoritmo ser diferente disto. Na verdade esta forma é bem simplificada para algumas situações reais. Por isto as perguntas devem ter detalhes.

Claro que tem várias outras formas de obter o mesmo resultado.

Comment: Creio que seja isso mesmo, aquele @id, ele ta pegando o id declarado no metodo?

Comment: Isso mesmo, você passa para a *query* através de um parâmetro declarado.

Comment: e no add parameters, essa linha ("id", id));   o id das aspas é o que?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0881fz2y(v=vs.110).aspx é o parâmetro da *query* que você está adicionando. Ele precisa saber onde ele vai encaixar o `id` passado pelo método dentro da *query*. Editei p/ ficar mais óbvio.